# C# - XmlSerializer Derived classes

Tags: c#, list, xmlserializer, derived-class

I'm on a problem who's driving me nuts, I looked everywhere on SO with no success. 
I'm trying to serialize some classes using .Net XmlSerializer.
I don't want to make a list of each objects (list[creditRating] and list
[Price]). I used 2 objects for my question but I have way more.

**The Output I want to reach :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<workspace xmlns="myNamespace">      
  <marketData date="2017-08-10">
   <creditRatings>                         <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->
    <creditRating id="TestAsset" rating="BBB" />
   </creditRatings>                        <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->
   <prices>                                <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->
     <price id="TestAsset" currency="CHF" price="100" />
     <price id="TestAsset2" currency="CHF" price="100" />
    <prices>                               <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->
  </marketData>
  <marketData date="2017-08-11">
    <creditRatings>                        <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->
     <creditRating id="TestAsset" rating="B" />
     <creditRating id="TestAsset2" rating="AAA" />
    </creditRatings>                        <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->
  </marketData>
</workspace>
```

As you can see I managed to create everything except the brackets around "creditRating" and "price". I tryed fiddling with [XmlInclude] and [XmlArrayItem] Attributes with no success.

I want to make a single list of abstract base class so I can easily populate them then use xmlSerializer to do the rest.

This is my entire code.

```
class Program
    {
        [XmlRoot("workspace")]
        public class Workspace
        {
            [XmlElement("marketData")]
            public List<MarketData> MarkeDatas { get; set; } = new List<MarketData>();
        }
        public class MarketData
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "date", DataType = "date")]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("creditRating", typeof(CreditRatingsMarketData))]
            [XmlElement("price", typeof(PricesMarketData))]
            public List<MarketDataItem> MarketDataItems { get; set; }
        }
        public abstract class MarketDataItem
        {
            [XmlIgnore]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

        }
        public class CreditRatingsMarketData : MarketDataItem
        {
            [XmlAttribute("rating")]
            public string CreditRating { get; set; }
        }

        public class PricesMarketData : MarketDataItem
        {
            [XmlAttribute("price")]
            public double Price { get; set; }
        }
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listMd = new List<MarketDataItem>
            {
                new CreditRatingsMarketData {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5), CreditRating = "BBB", Id = "TestAsset"},
                new CreditRatingsMarketData {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4), CreditRating = "B", Id = "TestAsset"},
                new PricesMarketData {Date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5), Id = "TestAsset", Price = 100}
            };
            var mds = listMd.GroupBy(c => c.Date)
                .Select(c => new MarketData {Date = c.Key, MarketDataItems = c.ToList()})
                .ToList();

            var ws = new Workspace { MarkeDatas = mds };

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Workspace));
            var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, ws);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: " I don't want to make a list of each objects (list[creditRating] and list [Price])." - but you have multiple of them for one parent object, so how else do you want to represent that? Just have two distinct `CreditRating` properties? What if there are more than two credit ratings or prices?

Comment: I already can have multiple creditRating and multiple price. The only thing I'm missing is the <creditRatings> and <prices> tags around the <creditRating> and <price> tags. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK so you want a single collection property that contains all price and creditrating data?

Comment: Exactly but I need an extra tag around them. you can see those tags in the output I want to reach on  the line where the comment :  <!-- those are the tags I cant make :( -->

Comment: I don't know that there's a way to do that with attributes alone.  You may need to implement the [IXmlSerializable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) and manually generate XML using an `XMLWriter`.  If you're willing to have multiple collection properties then you can certainly do it with attributes.  Personally I'd do it that way since there's not a natural "parent" type to both prices and credit ratings.